# Android Wait until Text to Speech OnInit is called

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I had an issue where Text to Speech would not speak anything.  I realised this was due to the fact that I was attempting to call 'Speak()' before TTS had initialised.

I need to wait until TTS has initialised, so that I can call 'Speak()' successfully.  I thought doing something along the lines of this would work:

```
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        mTTSInitialised = true;
    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initialisation Failed!");
    }
}

...

while(!mTTSInitialised){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But this fails to initialise at all.  Is there a way to do this effectively?

Answer (score 2):

The initialisation of the Text to Speech engine is asynchronous, which is why you realised you have to 'wait' for it to complete, before requesting that it processes an utterance.

Even when it eventually initialises successfully, it can be subsequently killed by the system, or it can of course fail to initialise, so you always need to be ready to handle a request to speak, where the engine isn't prepared.

Add the following helper class

```
public class PendingTTS {

    private String pendingUtterance;
    private int pendingQueueType;

    public String getPendingUtterance() {
        return this.pendingUtterance;
    }

    public void setPendingUtterance(@NonNull final String pendingUtterance) {
        this.pendingUtterance = pendingUtterance;
    }

    public int getPendingQueueType() {
        return this.pendingQueueType;
    }

    public void setPendingQueueType(final int pendingQueueType) {
        this.pendingQueueType = pendingQueueType;
    }
}
```

Assuming you're using an `Activity`, you need to declare the following variables:

```
private volatile PendingTTS pendingTTS;
private static final int MAX_INIT_ATTEMPTS = 4;
private volatile int initCount;
```

and initialise the Text to Speech object in `onCreate()`

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(YOURActivity.this, YOURonInitListener);
```

In your `onInitListener` you would check if there is any pending speech:

```
@Override
public void onInit(final int status) {

    switch (status) {

        case TextToSpeech.SUCCESS:
            initCount = 0;
            // Set up tts stuff
            tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(YOURprogressListener);

            if (pendingTTS != null) {

                // We have pending speech, process it and check the result

                int speechResult = tts.speak(pendingTTS.getPendingUtterance(),pendingTTS.getPendingQueueType(),
                        // remaining tts variables here)

                switch (speechResult){

                    case TextToSpeech.SUCCESS:

                        // Result was successful
                        pendingTTS = null;

                        break;
                    case TextToSpeech.ERROR:
                        // Speech failed
                        // Check if it has repeatedly failed up to the max attempts
                        if(initCount < MAX_INIT_ATTEMPTS){
                            initCount ++;
                            tts = new TextToSpeech(YOURActivity.this, YOURonInitListener);
                        } else {
                            // Totally broken - let the user know it's not working
                        }

                        break;
                }
            } else {
                // there was nothing to process
            }

            break;
        case TextToSpeech.ERROR:

            // Check if it has repeatedly failed up to the max attempts
            if(initCount < MAX_INIT_ATTEMPTS){
                initCount ++;
                tts = new TextToSpeech(YOURActivity.this, YOURonInitListener);
            } else {
                // Totally broken - let the user know it's not working
            }

            break;
    }
```

I've glued the above together from my code - where the speech and initialisation methods are all separated, but I tried to give you an overview above of everything you need to handle.

Elsewhere in your code, when you make a `tts.speak(//stuff here)` request, you need to check the result as demonstrated above, to make sure it was successful. Again, in my code, this is separated into one single method. If it does fail, you need to set the PendingTTS parameters prior to attempting to initialise again:

```
    pendingTTS = new PendingTTS();
    pendingTTS.setPendingQueueType(// your queue type);
    pendingTTS.setPendingUtterance(// your utterance);
```

It is is successful, make sure `pendingTTS` is set to null.

The overall design is that if the initialisation failed, it will attempt to initialise again, up to the maximum allowed attempts. If the speech fails, it will attempt to initialise the engine again, firstly setting the `PendingTTS` parameters.

Hope you managed to follow that.

Comment: What if you attempt to use speak(), but it has not yet initialised?  If you do it like you have suggested, wouldn't there be a considerable delay in say, clicking a button and it speaking (as you'd have to reinitialise and wait for onInit to be fired?)  Would it be possible to do something like: detect whether or not it has been initialised, if it hasn't, display a progress dialog until it has?

Comment: @Daniel Your speak method would attempt to speak as normal, in any implementation. If it returns `ERROR` you'll need to attempt to initialise the engine and then process any pending speech, as demonstrated above. In most cases you would hope it is already initialised, so it will speak immediately. Otherwise, you could raise a notification between starting the initialisation and remove it when your `UtteranceProgressListener` calls 'onStart'

Answer (score 1):

Hmm..
Not a very good idea.

You can try to add the text to the TTS queue and let it do it's work. This snippet can be inside button click, etc as:

```
tts.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

Small [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/) that would help.

Comment: This is incorrect. The ProgressListener tracks the speech, not the initialisation of the engine

Comment: My bad, swayed with flow that I have where I create audio. Updated the answer.